# No. Of LI Solutions to a Non homogeneous system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Let A be an n order matrix with Nulity m . I know the number of linearly independent solutions to the homogeneous equation is  m .
But what will be the number of linearly independent solutions if the system is nonhomogeneous system .
I thought it would be same m
Since the solution set is nothing but a translation or a parallel of the homogeneous system.
But my teacher said It is m+1

Please provide your views

Answer (score 2):

*IF* the equation $Ax=b$ *has* a solution, i.e. $b$ is in the column space of $A$, then the set of solutions is indeed an $m$ dimensional affine subspace $W$, specifically $W=x_0+\ker A$ where $x_0$ is any single solution.

If $b\ne 0$ and $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is a basis for $\ker A$, then as $x_0\notin\ker A$ it must be linearly independent from $v_j$, and thus the vectors
$$x_0,\ x_0+v_1,\ \dots,\ x_0+v_m$$
are all solutions and are linearly independent.
Since $W\subseteq{\rm span}(x_0,\ker A)$ which has dimension $m+1$, there can't be more linearly independent vectors in $W$.